# Skip over a value in the range function in python

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, range

What is the pythonic way of looping through a range of numbers and skipping over one value?  For example, the range is from 0 to 100 and I would like to skip 50.

Edit:
Here's the code that I'm using

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    x= listRow(list, i)
    for j in range (#0 to len(list) not including x#)
        ...
```

Comment: The `continue` statement with a conditional?

Comment: I could do that but is there any way to get it in the structure of the  loop itself?

Comment: what are you doing in the loop?

Answer (score 108, accepted):

You can use any of these:

```
# Create a range that does not contain 50
for i in [x for x in xrange(100) if x != 50]:
    print i

# Create 2 ranges [0,49] and [51, 100] (Python 2)
for i in range(50) + range(51, 100):
    print i

# Create a iterator and skip 50
xr = iter(xrange(100))
for i in xr:
    print i
    if i == 49:
        next(xr)

# Simply continue in the loop if the number is 50
for i in range(100):
    if i == 50:
        continue
    print i
```

Comment: The third suggestion throws TypeError because you did not explicitly create an iterator

Comment: (1) creates two lists, (2) concatenates two lists, (3) does not work, xrange is not a iterator. (4) should use xrange to avoid creating a list, and is the so far best solution.

Comment: How does (1) create two lists? `xrange(100)` is not a list. And you can avoid creating the second list by returning a generator instead: `for i in (x for x in xrange(100) if x is not 50)`

Comment: @Daniel: 1/ creates one list only because of xrange. 2/ I know, not the most efficient, but clear. 3/ typo, thanks for pointing out 4/ probably, yes. (but for a 100 elements it is fine)

Comment: #2 with Python 3.x: `...list(range(50)) + list(range(51, 100)):`

Comment: @loxosceles or using `itertools.chain(range(50), range(51, 100))` instead, to avoid creating lists (although my initial solution is indeed creating 2 lists)

Comment: #2 doesn't work in Python 3. The rest are all quite inefficient.

Comment: @Acumenus this question is tagged `python`, not `python3`. If you have more efficient solutions, please share them so everyone can benefit :)

Answer (score 13):

In addition to the Python 2 approach here are the equivalents for Python 3:

```
# Create a range that does not contain 50
for i in [x for x in range(100) if x != 50]:
    print(i)

# Create 2 ranges [0,49] and [51, 100]
from itertools import chain
concatenated = chain(range(50), range(51, 100))
for i in concatenated:
    print(i)

# Create a iterator and skip 50
xr = iter(range(100))
for i in xr:
    print(i)
    if i == 49:
        next(xr)

# Simply continue in the loop if the number is 50
for i in range(100):
    if i == 50:
        continue
    print(i)
```

Ranges are lists in Python 2 and iterators in Python 3.

Answer (score 2):

If the index of the skipped value is known, it is not necessary to compare each number:

```
import itertools

m, n = 5, 10
for i in itertools.chain(range(m), range(m + 1, n)):
    print(i)  # skips m = 5
```

As an aside, you woudn't want to use `(*range(m), *range(m + 1, n))` even though it works because it will expand the iterables into a tuple and this is memory inefficient.

---

Credit: comment by njzk2

Answer (score 1):

```py
for i in range(0, 101):
    if i != 50:
        do sth
    else:
        pass
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use set.difference:

```
   list(set.difference(                                                                                                                                              
       set(range(0, 32)),                                                                                                                                         
       set((0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 15, 20, 21))))
```

result:

```
Out[37]: [11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range(100):
    if i == 50:
        continue
    dosomething
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you want to do. For example you could stick in some conditionals like this in your comprehensions:

```
# get the squares of each number from 1 to 9, excluding 2
myList = [i**2 for i in range(10) if i != 2]
print(myList)

# --> [0, 1, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me;

example:

```
x = ['apple', 'orange', 'grape', 'lion', 'banana', 'watermelon', 'onion', 'cat',]

for xr in x:
    if xr in 'onion':
        print('onion is a vegetable')
        continue
    if (xr not in 'lion' and xr not in 'cat'):
        print(xr, 'is a fruit')
```

Output -->

```
apple is a fruit
orange is a fruit
grape is a fruit
banana is a fruit
watermelon is a fruit
onion is a vegetable
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to skip over consecutive numbers where the initial number may be unknown, it is best to use a `while` loop.

```
# Loop through a range of numbers from 0 to 100 and skip over number 50 as well
# as the next 3 consecutive numbers (51, 52, 53). Additionally, skip over 11 to 14.

i = 0
initial_skip_num = (50, 11, )
while i < 100:
    if i in initial_skip_num:
        i += 4
    print(i)
    i += 1
```

Output:

```
0
1
...
9
10
15
16
...
48
49
54
55
...
```

This is helpful if the initial number to skip is unknown or multiple consecutive numbers need to be skipped

Answer (score 0):

There is a `set` based approach you can use as part of the for-loop or list comprehension whatever, for example:

```py
for x in set(range(100)) - {50}:
    print(x)
```

Answer (score -1):

what you could do, is put an if statement around everything inside the loop that you want kept away from the 50.
e.g.

```
for i in range(0, len(list)):
    if i != 50:
        x= listRow(list, i)
        for j in range (#0 to len(list) not including x#)
```