# good style to introduce python variables within a loop

Tags: python

I have a C++ background and I'm learning Python. I am writing code which needs to extract a particular value from a `for` loop:

```
seventh_value = None   # ** my question is about this line
for index in range(1, 10):
    value = f(index)
    # we have a special interest in the seventh value
    if index == 7:
        seventh_value = value
    # (do other things with value here)

# make use of seventh_value here
```

In C++ I'd need to declare seventh_value before the for loop to ensure its scope is not limited to the for loop. In Python I do not need to do this. My question is whether it's good style to omit the initial assignment to seventh_value.

I understand that if the loop doesn't iterate at least 7 times then I can avoid a NameError by assigning to seventh_value prior to the loop. Let's assume that it is clear it will iterate at least 7 times (as in the above example where I've hard-coded 10 iterations).

I also understand that there may be other ways to extract a particular value from an iteration. I'm really just wondering about whether it's good style to introduce variables before a loop if they will be used after the loop.

The code I wrote above looks clear to me, but I think I'm just seeing it with C++ eyes.

Comment: In the general case where `seventh_value` may or may not be set in the loop, I think this is a reasonable approach. At the end of the loop you could check if `seventh_value` is still `None` (assuming you won't encounter `None` as a value.) This is probably just opinion, but I think checking if the value is still `None` at the end of the list to say it wasn't set is far nicer than trying to handle it by working around a `NameError`. An alternate approach is to have a separate boolean such as `seventh_value_set = False` and then set that to true if the value is set in the loop.

Comment: It is subjective, but personally I would initialise it to `None` before the loop.

Comment: In this case, I would declare before the loop, and unwrap. As long as f isn't too expensive, I would declare `seventh_value = f(7)` I realize that this is a hugely simplified case, but this type of logic works fairly often.

Comment: Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089924/skip-over-a-value-in-the-range-function-in-python  
You can construct a range that simply excludes the 7th value and then call f(7) when you assign.

Comment: This post has some relevant discussion http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3611760/scoping-in-python-for-loops

Answer (score 2):

This is a fine approach to set the value to `None` before the for-loop. Do not worry too much. Personally, I feel as long as code is readable by someone who has no idea at all -- it is fine.

That being said, there's a slightly better (pythonic) way to avoid the problem altogether. **Note** that the following will **not** do anything with the value at every iteration -- just the "special interest" part. Further, I am assuming `f(..)` does not cause any side-effects (like changes states of variables outside (like global variables). If it does, the line below is definitely not for you.

```
seventh_value = next(f(i) for i in range(1,10) if i == 7)
```

The above construct run until i==7, and calls `f(i)` only when i=7 never else.

Comment: This code is not equivalent to the code the question is about since that code calls `f` with every index and also does something with the return value. Yours looks like `f(7)`.

Comment: Yes, if there is a "special interest" in only the 7th index, then why call `f(..)` on every index -- as I have called out in the last line of my answer.

Comment: Because f might have side effects and because, as the question says, the loop does something with the return value of _every_ call. What you've ended up is a confusing non-answer and you should probably remove it.

Comment: If `f` is a pure function, this solution should work exactly as OP's does. If `f` has side effects (as @pvg mentions), I think this should work: `[f(i) for i in range(1,10)][6])`.

Comment: @Tagc no it doesn't. see '# (do other things with value here)' in the question. Also this is basically a really convoluted way to call `f(someconstant)`. It is not 'pythonic', just pointless.

Comment: @pvg: Fair enough. I have updated the answer with a few details on purity of functions, and when that generator expression can/must not be used.

Comment: @Tagc: I missed it too!

Answer (score 1):

It's only partially a matter of style. You need to do *something* to ensure your code doesn't raise an (uncaught) `NameError` following the loop, so your two choices are

1. Ensure that the `NameError` cannot happen by making an unconditional assignment to `seventh_value`.
2. Wrap the code that accesses `seventh_value` in a `try` block to catch and (presumably) ignore the possible `NameError`.

View from this perspective, and without knowing more about your code, I think you would agree that #1 is preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that `seventh_value` should be set and you count on it in your program logic, you might even want your code to crash with `NameError` and write it without prior `seventh_value` definition.

If you are sure that `seventh_value` might not be set when all code works just fine, you should probably define `seventh_value` as you do in the example and check later if it was set at all.

Comment: Ignoring an exception that you can do something about is not a good idea.

Comment: I can't imagine it's pythonic to attempt to handle every possible exception in a program. For example every time we divide integers we don't say "if x != 0" or "catch ZeroDivisionError". It must depend on the context, and in my case I was tried to emphasize that it's clear seventh_value will indeed be assigned.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it exactly how you suggest, and if you try it, you will find it works exactly how you want.

However, there is a better, (imho more pythonic) way, that totally avoids the need to pre-initialize the variable.

```
results = []
for index in range(1, 10):
    value = f(index)
    # (do other things with value here)

    results.append(value)     

seventh_value = results[6] #6 because index 1 is at location 0 in the list.
# make use of seventh_value here
```

Now that you have a simple `for` loop, it can easily be refactored into a list comprehension:

```
results = [f(index) for index in range(1, 10)]

for value in results:
    # (do other things with value here)

seventh_value = results[7]
# make use of seventh_value here
```

Whether you decide to go that far will depend on how complex your `(do other things with value here)` is.

Comment: Shouldn't the seventh value in this case be at index 6?