# summing together elements in list in python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists, `t` and `e`, of the same size: to each element `t[i]` corresponds an element `e[i]`. I want to print each pair `t[i] e[i]`, but summing together elements `e[i]` and `e[i-1]` whenever the corresponding `t[i]` and `t[i-1]` are closer than 1. In this case, elements `e[5]` and `e[4]` should be summed up, since the corresponding `t[5]-t[4]<1`. The point is, I want to REPLACE the 4th elements with the 4th+5th elements, without printing the 5th elements. My code is:

```
t = [1, 5, 10, 16, 20, 21, 28, 33, 39, 42, 45, 50, 56]
e = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

for j in range(1,12):
    if t[j]-t[j-1] <= 1:
        print t[j-1], e[j-1]+e[j]
    else:
        if t[j] > t[j-1]:
            print t[j-1], e[j-1]
```

But this gives me:

```
1 A
5 B
10 C
16 D
20 EF
21 F
28 G
33 H
39 I
42 J
45 K
```

I don't want to print `21 F`, as it is already summed in the `20 EF`. How can I do that? Is there a way to increase the counter `i` at the end of the `if` condition? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Related built-in functions: [`len()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len),  [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) and [`enumerate()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: Should the combining of characters ever go beyond two?

Comment: Do you want to print `21 G` then, or skip `21` entirely?

Comment: He wants to skip 21 and F entirely. Next should be "28 G".

Answer (score 1):

Another solution is a while loop :

```
t = [1, 5, 10, 16, 20, 21, 28, 33, 39, 42, 45, 50, 56]
e = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

j = 1
while j < len(t):
    if t[j]-t[j-1] <= 1:
        print t[j-1], e[j-1]+e[j]
        j += 1
    else:
        if t[j] > t[j-1]:
            print t[j-1], e[j-1]
    j += 1
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't think about the while loop! I was trying to increase the counter from inside the for loop and it didn't work!

Comment: Ok, yeah, that's maybe the best solution. ^^

Comment: Produces wrong result. First line of output is `"56 MA"`. Thats because you access `t[-1]`, which is 56, in the first iteration.

Answer (score 0):

If it's just about the output:

```
for i in range(0, len(t)):
    if i<1:
        print( t[i], e[i], end="")
    else:
        if t[i] - t[i-1] > 1:
            print()
            print( t[i], e[i], end="")
        else:
            print( e[i], end="")
```

prints

```
1 A
5 B
10 C
16 D
20 EF
28 G
33 H
39 I
42 J
45 K
50 L
56 M
```

Answer (score -1):

Either you use the solution down here or you look at this post: [Skip over a value in the range function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089924/skip-over-a-value-in-the-range-function-in-python)

```
t = [1, 5, 10, 16, 20, 21, 28, 33, 39, 42, 45, 50, 56]
e = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M']

skip = False
for j in range(len(t)):
    if not skip:
        if t[j]-t[j-1] <= 1:
            print t[j-1], e[j-1]+e[j]
            skip = True
        else:
            if t[j] > t[j-1]:
                print t[j-1], e[j-1]
    else:
        skip = False

>1 A
>5 B
>10 C
>16 D
>20 EF
>28 G
>33 H
>39 I
>42 J
>45 K
>50 L
```

Comment: What about `"56 M"`?

Comment: Just copied the code from OP. The static range instead of len(t) or something similar is another chapter.