# Python: How to generate a range skipping every 4th number?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need to create a range skipping over every 4th number, starting from 5. For example, if the range a is from 1-20, then the numbers 5,9,13,17 will be excluded.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

What I tried is creating a regular range, and then a second range consisting the numbers I want to skip, and then remove the second range from the first one.

```
a = list(range(1,21))
b = list(range(5,21,4))
for x in b:
   if x in a:
      a.remove(x)
```

This works, but not for a very large range.
Is there a more efficient way to do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip over a value in the range function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089924/skip-over-a-value-in-the-range-function-in-python)

Comment: @RushabhMehta Not much of a duplicate.

Comment: ranges only support start, stop, step, by definition.  Which parts of the range API do you need to keep? sized? O(1) membership? O(1) memory? reversed? slicable?

Answer (score 8):

**Solution:**

For efficiency, I would recommend using a generator expression like this:

```
r = (x for x in range(1,21) if x not in range(5,21,4))
```

or, equivalently, and without needing to write the upper bound twice:

```
r = (x for x in range(1,21) if x == 1 or x % 4 != 1)
```

You can use this generator as you would use a normal sequence (list/tuple)*, and convert the generator to a list with `list()` if you absolutely need to.

**Justification:**

The advantage of this approach is that it **does not require storing all of the items in memory**, so you can make the upper bound arbitrarily large without any performance problems.

---

*(Sort of-there are caveats, as mentioned by the commenters below. e.g. if you want fast membership checks, you would be better off just using the two ranges separately)

Comment: A generator is different from a range object, though.  ranges are sized (len) and support O(1) membership test.

Comment: Upvote for the second one, I actually find that more flexible, And understandable, but that may just be my warped mind :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use a `set` and another list comprehension:

```
a = range(1, 21)
b = set(range(5, 21, 4))

[i for i in a if i not in b]
# [1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

You could remove the `set` from the second range, but I am finding this is slower than set inclusion checking:

***Functions***

```
def chris(m):
  a = range(1, m)
  b = set(range(5, m, 4))
  return [i for i in a if i not in b]

def chris2(m):
  a = range(1, m)
  b = range(5, m, 4)
  return [i for i in a if i not in b]


def ollin(m):
  return list(x for x in range(1,m) if x not in range(5,m,4))

def ollin2(m):
  return list(x for x in range(1,m) if x == 1 or x % 4 != 1)

def smac(m):
  return [v for i, v in enumerate(range(1,m)) if i == 0 or i % 4 != 0]
```

***Setup***

```
from timeit import timeit

import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

res = pd.DataFrame(
       index=['chris', 'chris2', 'ollin', 'ollin2', 'smac'],
       columns=[10, 50, 100, 500, 1000, 5000, 10000],
       dtype=float
)

for f in res.index: 
    for c in res.columns:
        stmt = '{}(c)'.format(f)
        setp = 'from __main__ import c, {}'.format(f)
        res.at[f, c] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=50)

ax = res.div(res.min()).T.plot(loglog=True) 
ax.set_xlabel("N"); 
ax.set_ylabel("time (relative)");

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: No need for `b = set(range(5, 21, 4))`, range objects have constant-time membership testing for integer

Comment: I'm getting slower timings (even including the overhead to create the set) if I just use `range(5, 21, 4)`

Comment: Are you on Python 3? How are you timing it? In any event, depending on various things, it will be slower or faster, but both should be *constant time*

Comment: I'll post my timings

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I confirm: the `set` is twice as fast as the `range`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this list comprehension:

```
>>> print ([v for i, v in enumerate(range(1,21)) if i == 0 or i % 4 != 0])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps a set difference?

```
numItems = 21
r1 = set(range(1,numItems))
r2 = set(range(5,numItems,4))

r3 = list(r1 - r2)
```

Comment: I had that same thought of using sets but was didnt think it would preserve the integers in increasing order but was surprised to see that the order was preserved!

    list(set((5,4,3,2,1)))  =  [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] !  However  list(set(('y', 'c', 'r', 'd'))) =  ['d', 'c', 'y', 'r']           weird ...

Answer (score 1):

If we consider `numpy`

```
import numpy as np 
a=np.arange(1,21)
a[np.logical_or(a%4!=1,a==1)]
Out[209]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  6,  7,  8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20])
```

Answer (score 1):

Writing your own generator function could be useful:

```
def weird_range():
   for i in range(1, 21):
      if i < 5 or i % 4 != 1:
         yield i

>>> list(weird_range())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

This will let you do all manner of bizarre sequences.

---

Alternate is to create your own range object:

```
class WeirdRange:
   def __contains__(self, val):
      return val < 5 or val % 4 != 1

>>> list(_ for _ in range(1,21) if _ in WeirdRange())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

---

Or you can create your own Iterator:

```
class WeirdIterator:

   def __init__(self):
      self._idx = 0

   def __iter__(self):
      return self

   def __next__(self):
      self._idx += 1
      if self._idx >= 5  and  self._idx % 4 == 1:
         self._idx += 1
      if self._idx > 20:
         raise StopIteration()
      return self._idx

>>> list(WeirdIterator())
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 16, 18, 19, 20]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
a = list(range(1,21))

for x in a:
    if x!=1 and x%4==1:
        continue
    print(x)
```

Comment: Your answer is incorrect - please check it carefully and fix

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.