# Calculate skip n times number inside while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, math

My Code that I use

```
loop = 1
skip_n_time1 = 1 # skip n time from 1
skip_n_time2 = 5 # skip n time from 1
while(loop<20):
  print(loop);
  if(loop%skip_n_time1 == 0):
    # do my task
    print("skip_n_time1")
  if(loop%skip_n_time2 == 0):
    # do my task
    print("skip_n_time2")
  loop+=1
```

**I does not get result I want**

*** `skip_n_time1` execute every time

I want to execute `if` after `n` times

**I want to execute if in [n] time Example:**

if use `1` it should execute in `loop` count `[1] 2 [3]  4  [5] 6 [7] 8 [9]`

if use `2` it should execute in `loop` count `[1] 2  3  [4]  5  6 [7] 8  9`

if use `3` it should execute in `loop` count `[1] 2  3   4  [5] 6  7  8 [9]`

Comment: every number mod 1 is 0 (`if(loop%skip_n_time1 == 0):`).

Comment: How I can skip 1 by 1 or 2 by 2 etc check : I want to execute if in [n] time Example:

Comment: Please don't tag questions as both [tag:python-2.7] and [tag:python-3.x] -- unless you specifically need code which works on Python 2.7 you should probably focus exclusively on Python 3 in this day and age.

Comment: @LuckyNegi Use `if(loop % 2 == 0):` for skipping 1 at a time.Or just `res = list(range(1, 10, 2))`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Skip over a value in the range function in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089924/skip-over-a-value-in-the-range-function-in-python)

Comment: for i in range(1, 20, skip_n_time):
...     print(i)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this code snippet:**

```
loop = 1
skip_n_time1 = 1 # skip n time from 1
skip_n_time2 = 5 # skip n time from 1
while(loop<20):
    print_str = str(loop) + " "
    if( (loop-1) % skip_n_time1 == 0 ):
        print_str += "skip_n_time1"
    if( (loop-1) % skip_n_time2 == 0 ):
        print_str += " skip_n_time2"
    loop+=1
    print(print_str)
```