# Excluding list of values from range with large numbers

Tags: python, list, range

I want a sample through

```
random.sample(range(11111111111,99999999999), len(df.index))
```

However, I have list of values I do not want to be included in the sample, and therefore want to remove it from the range before.

Problem: Converting the range to a list for filtering results in a Memory Error - I believe it takes to much memory

Any suggestions?

Comment: You might also get interested in taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator-iterable-iterator

Comment: Is that your actual range? How large is `len(df.index))`? How large is the exclude-list, and how many unique values does it have in the range?

Answer (score 0):

First, define a generator to create an infinite sequence of random numbers using `yield` so the numbers are calculated only once they are needed:

```
from random import randint

exclusion_set = {11111111111, 22222222222, 33333333333}

def random_number_generator(min_value : int, max_value : int):
    while True:
        i = randint(min_value, max_value)
        if i not in exclusion_set:
            yield i
```

Then, use [`itertools.islice()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.islice) to generate as many random numbers as needed.

Full code:

```
from random import randint
from itertools import islice
from time import perf_counter

min_value = 11111111111
max_value = 99999999999
num_samples = 1000000
exclusion_set = {11111111111, 22222222222, 33333333333}

def random_number_generator(min_value : int, max_value : int):
    while True:
        i = randint(min_value, max_value)
        if i not in exclusion_set:
            yield i

start_time = perf_counter()
result = islice(random_number_generator(min_value, max_value), num_samples)
result = list(result)
end_time = perf_counter()

#print(result)
print(len(result))
print(end_time - start_time)
```

**Notes:**

- The way the random numbers are calculated is probably improvable.
- For more info, as suggested by `RandomGuy`, check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12581437/python-random-sample-with-a-generator-iterable-iterator).

---

If you need the result list to not contain duplicated values, add a "seen" `set` in the generator to keep track of already generated numbers:

```
def random_number_generator(min_value : int, max_value : int):
    seen = set()
    while True:
        i = randint(min_value, max_value)
        if i not in exclusion_set and i not in seen:
            seen.add(i)
            yield i
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain a O(NlogX) solution *(where N is sample size and X is number of exclusions)* by building a list of offsets and reducing your sample range by the number of excluded values.  Then use a binary search to adjust the sample values back to the full range by applying the offsets to increase them (i.e. performing the skips):

```
import random
from bisect import bisect_right

minValue    = 111
maxValue    = 999
exclusions  = [121, 131, 141, 151] # must be sorted
offsets     = [n-i for i,n in enumerate(exclusions)]
sampleSize  = 15

def getSample():
    S = random.sample(range(minValue,maxValue+1-len(exclusions)), sampleSize)
    return [n + bisect_right(offsets,n) for n in S]
```

output:

```
print(getSample())
[574, 891, 953, 210, 331, 253, 117, 845, 572, 885, 699, 799, 563, 857, 532]
```

checking for validity of the output:

```
excludedSet = set(exclusions)
for _ in range(10000):
    s = getSample()
    if excludedSet.intersection(s):
        print("failed exclusions",s)
        break
else:
    print("all samples are compliant")

--> all samples are compliant
```

*Note that this assumes that the number of excluded values is reasonable.  If you are excluding whole subsets or patterns of values, a different solution would probably be better.  You would have to be more specific in your question though.*

Answer (score -1):

If performance is not critical, you can keep sampling integers in the desired range and skipping them if they are undesired, as follows:

```
import random

skip = {111_111_111, 321_321_321}
target_samples = 10
samples = []
while len(samples) < target_samples:
    n = random.randint(111_111_111, 999_999_999)
    if n not in skip:
        samples.append(n)
print(samples)
```

Comment: Use a set for `skip`, as linear search in a list is extremely inefficient

Comment: That is actually the approach I come up with for now, however I feel like it is not really elegant and hoped for a better solution

Comment: @oluo.acn Yeah, I'm not sure if there is an elegant solution. There are some ways to exclude values from `range` discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24089924/skip-over-a-value-in-the-range-function-in-python), with perhaps `itertools.chain` looking the most promising, depending on the distribution of your skip values.